# AWS Elasticsearch: how to load data from one cluster into another

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

on **AWS** Elasticsearch, is there convienient way to load data from one cluster into another ?

thx

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by restoring a snapshot of your AWS Elasticsearch cluster, if you have enabled automated snapshot, while configuring the cluster.

You may want to take a look at the **Working with Manual Index Snapshots (AWS CLI)** section the in the below AWS Elasticsearch document?

[Managing Amazon Elasticsearch Service Domains](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html#es-managedomains-snapshots)

Below is an excerpt:

> Amazon Elasticsearch Service (Amazon ES) takes daily automated
>   snapshots of the primary index shards in an Amazon ES domain, as
>   described in Configuring Snapshots. However, you must contact the AWS
>   Support team to restore an Amazon ES domain with an automated
>   snapshot. If you need greater flexibility, you can take snapshots
>   manually and manage them in a snapshot repository, an Amazon S3
>   bucket.